# How to automatically register new subclasses?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm working on the reporting module of our web-application. There are six reports available to the client, each of them has a **code**. The problem is that now the module is not closed for modification with respect to potential addition of new reports, thus violating OCP.

To elucidate, I have the following set of classes:

A generic report class, which all other reports inherit:

```java
public abstract class Report 
{
    private final String code;

    Report(String code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() { return code; }

    public abstract byte[] generate();
}
```

A servlet which manages POST requests for report generation:

```java
public class ReportServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Report requested = ReportRegistry.lookup(req.getParameter("report_code"));
        byte[] bytes = requested.generate();
        // attach bytes to response
    }

}
```

Report registry, which stores all existing reports for later access:

```java
public class ReportRegistry
{
    private static final Map<String, Report> registry = new HashMap<>();

    static
    {
        // Violates OCP!
        registerReport( GlobalReport.getInstance() );
        registerReport( AvailablePackagesReport.getInstance() );
        registerReport( BadgeReport.getInstance() );
        registerReport( PlacementReport.getInstance() );
        registerReport( TerminalReport.getInstance() );
        registerReport( VerActReport.getInstance() );
    }

    private ReportRegistry() { }

    static void registerReport(final Report report)
    {
        registry.put(report.getCode(), report);
    }

    public static Report lookup(final String reportCode)
    {
        return registry.get(reportCode);
    }
}
```

However, `ReportRegistry` violates OCP, since we need to add an entry to its static block every time a new report is created.

My question is: how can I make any new subclass of `Report` to be registered automatically, without any explicit mentioning?

Comment: Maybe you could use services (java.util.ServiceLoader)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think OCP would be more applicable to `Report` itself, and that having `ReportRegistry` sitting outside of the class hierarchy would be a valid design.

That said, if you want to avoid modifying `ReportRegistry` each time you create a `Report` subclass, you could use some reflection tricks to seek out all such subclasses, or create an annotation that `ReportRegistry` could search for to register all classes with instances.

Comment: Or simply (but risky), register the report directly from the `Report` constructor

Comment: @Lino, I've tried that approach, it didn't work, because classes were loaded but not initialized. You still need to call their static methods explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections. I have never tried this library but it looks like it does what you want (retrieving all subclasses of a known class).

You could then register them in your `ReportRegistry` static block.